# Can an ATK outrun the destruction of a structure, while still building up?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I was wondering if you could drive an ATK, or a quad crasher for that matter, faster than a single ramp can be destroyed.

Take this example:
You're driving an ATK up and the passenger is building a ramp. Someone shoots the ramp out from **the bottom** of the ramp. Can you continue driving and building the ramp faster than you will get knocked to the ground and die?

Comment: What do you mean by 'dune buggy'? Are you talking about the quad Crasher or just another word for ATK?

Comment: @GamerM quad crasher

Comment: If no one answers by tommrow, I will do an experiment tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter how fast you're going, you cannot continue building onto a structure as it is being destroyed.

Comment: That's not the question. The OP didn't mention building in this question.

Comment: @GamerM That is how I understood this part of the question: "Can you continue driving *and building the ramp* faster than you will get knocked to the ground and die?"

Comment: and building?- Ok, I admit I didn't see those two words. I understood it as can you keep driving up, without being knocked out, without the building part. Never mind

Comment: As a side note, I can't undownvote your question until you edit it. So sorry about that :/

Comment: Additionally, the question title DID NOT mention building.